Are there any datasets that have reconstructions of historic GDP that go further back in time than Maddison Project data?
As the title says, is there any alternative to Maddison Project data that would go more back in time, for roughly similar sample of countries/regions?

B. R. Mitchell has various data from 1750 to 1993 in his series "International Historical Statistics". For example, population data in Maddison generally starts from 1820 for most countries, but I think you can find earlier data in Mitchell.  Source: https://archive.org/search?query=International+historical+statistics
